# Translate Animation in Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, translate, translate-animation

I'm trying to do a simple CSS3 translate animation on a div and it seems to work on on all browsers except for Firefox. This is really grinding my gears. Here is my JS.

```
var translateAnimationTime = 1000;

$('.some-class').css({
    transform: 'translateX(0px)',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': translateAnimationTime + 'ms',
    'transition-duration': translateAnimationTime + 'ms'
});
```

And here is my CSS

```
.some-class {

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

  transition-property: all;

  -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  -moz-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.190, 1.000, 0.220, 1.000);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried every single vendor prefix as well. Should I be using animation-duration or transition-duration?

Comment: what is the animation goal here? going from translateZ(0) to translateX(0)?

Comment: The animation goal is to move something along the x axis via translateX. So horizontal movement. translateZ is there in order to trigger GPU accelerated animations

Comment: you are using 'animation-timing-function' instead of 'transition-timing-function' - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transitions

Answer (score 0):

try with -moz- also

```
$('.some-class').css({
    transform: 'translateX(0px)',
    '-webkit-transition-duration': translateAnimationTime + 'ms',
    '-moz-transition-duration': translateAnimationTime + 'ms',
    'transition-duration': translateAnimationTime + 'ms'
});
```